# Is my nurse dead for good?

Tags: terraria-mobile

When I enter the dungeon the nurse teleports with me and dies.

Is this a glitch? What can I do now that there is no nurse?

Answer (score 3):

NPCs and monsters can teleport through teleporters too.

And if you lose an NPC, they come back the next day.

Comment: Thanks! But I I'm trying to grind mobs they they teleport to me no teleported they die which sucks

Answer (score 0):

the only reason i could think of why she is teleporting is because there would be a queen statue trap wired up to a button, switch or pressure plate.